# prvalue vs xvalue for class types

Tags: c++, prvalue

I've got more confused when I see this question: [Is a class instantiation--`class_name()` a xvalue or a prvalue?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73917346/19495502) I'm trying to understand what does it mean by a class prvalue and a class xvalue. Someone tell me that they're called value category. But I think it would be better if I provide an example, because I'm very confused.

```
class myclass { public: myclass() {}; };

void myfunc(myclass c1){  }

int main(void)
{
   myfunc(myclass());
}
```

So what's `myclass()`? Is it a prvalue or xvalue?

I need a rule from the standard so that I wouldn't ask more questions.

Comment: Yes `myclass()` is prvalue.

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type.conv#2.sentence-3

Comment: It's a prvalue. Prvalues refer to freshly created objects.

Comment: Anyone can add language-lawyer tag? because the question says `I need a rule from the standard so that I wouldn't ask more questions.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `myclass()` is explicit type conversion using functional notation, per [expr.type.conv]/1:

> A simple-type-specifier or typename-specifier followed by a
> parenthesized optional expression-list or by a braced-init-list (the
> initializer) constructs a value of the specified type given the
> initializer [..]

Here, the *simple-type-specifier* `myclass` is followed by parenthesized expression-list `()` with an empty *initializer-list*. This expression constructs a value of type `myclass` from the empty initializer-list.

So you might ask, Is that constructed value is prvalue or xvalue or lvalue. So here we've to invoke the immediately next paragraph: [expr.type.conv]/2:

> If the initializer is a parenthesized single expression, the type
> conversion expression is equivalent to the corresponding cast
> expression. Otherwise, if the type is `cv void` and the initializer is
> `()` or `{}` (after pack expansion, if any), the expression is a prvalue
> of the specified type that performs no initialization. **Otherwise, the
> expression is a prvalue of the specified type whose result object is
> direct-initialized with the initializer.**

Our initializer is empty initializer-list, and the type is not `cv void`, so we've ended with the sentence that says:

> Otherwise, the expression is a prvalue of the specified type whose
> result object is direct-initialized with the initializer.

Hence, the expression `myclass()` is a prvalue, whose result object is direct-initialized, from the empty initializer-list, by calling the default constructor.